# WinDbg script parsing alias of double-quote

Tags: string, parsing, windbg

I'm working on a script that runs a couple of WinDbg commands, outputting the output of some, and parsing others using .foreach.

My problem is that when I try to run:

```
0: kd> dt -b -r 0xdeadbeef drivername!DRIVER_DEVICE_CONTEXT
```

The output looks something like this:

```
   +0x000 variable1 : 5
   +0x004 variable2 : 0
   +0x008 variable3 : 1
   +0x00c variable4 : 1
   +0x010 variable5 : 8
   +0x014 variable6 : (null)
   +0x018 variable7 : 1
   +0x01c table1 :  ""
    [00] 0 ''
    [01] 0 ''
    [02] 0 ''
    [03] 0 ''
```

...

Creating an alias 'command' which is that command, then running:

```
.foreach(word {command}) { .echo "word" }
```

will give the error:

```
Syntax error at .echo """"
```

Is there any way to just .continue if word is "" ??

Running al shows the following:

```
  Alias            Value  
 -------          -------
 command          dt -b -r 0xdeadbeef drivername!DRIVER_DEVICE_CONTEXT
 word             ""
```

Comment: I also posted this here, since there are relatively few people that are knowledgeable in WinDbg scripting.  I'll try to keep these two synced up.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a29e74c5-63f3-4478-8f44-780a2d774542/windbg-script-parsing-alias-of-doublequote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with single quotes:

```
.foreach(word {command}) { .echo 'word' }
```

Can I recommend you to use python with windbg? It will make your life easier :)

[pykd.codeplex.com](http://pykd.codeplex.com)

If it will not like to you, you always can return it back :).

For example:

```
DRIVER_DEVICE_CONTEXT = typeInfo( "drivername!DRIVER_DEVICE_CONTEXT" )

for fieldName, fieldType in DRIVER_DEVICE_CONTEXT:
   print fieldName
```

Comment: Well that works for echo but fails for $spat -- .foreach (word {command}) {.if($spat('""','word'){.echo Is}.else{.echo Isnt}}
Syntax error at '('""','+0x000'){.echo Is}.else{.echo Isnt}
   
I'll have to see about PyKd; I'm working on this script for someone else and I don't know how widely it will be deployed (and if everyone using this script have admin rights to install Python/PyKd)

Comment: While a WinDbg-native answer would be nice, this is a functional alternative.  Accepting as best answer (unless someone figures out a WinDbg native way)

Comment: you can use .catch to ignore errors:
.foreach(word {command}) { .catch { .if { $spat( "pattern", "${word}" ) { .echo "Found pattern" } } }
You will see error messages, but your script will reach to the end